# Need help with multi out BFD3 in Ableton 9.7.1

Tags: recording, ableton-live, wiring, ableton

I'm using BFD3 and I'd like to route the outputs of each channel into Ableton for further processing. What I'd like to do is:

1. For each channel N create a mono out N into Ableton
2. In Ableton have N corresponding audio tracks with respective channel

This perfectly possible but somehow the Ableton Audio From window shows only up to 8stereo and 8mono tracks of BFD3. Is this a limitation of Ableton itself or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: A picture of the problem
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify which edition of Live you are using? Live Intro will probably limited in this way, and it looks like even Live Studio may or may not support complete multi-channel output (it only allows 12 "send and return tracks" - not sure if BFD uses returns or audio tracks).

Answer (score 1):

Despite my comment, this might only be limited by the number of audio channels your edition of Live supports. Here are the instructions from the Ableton web site ([link here](https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209773065-How-to-access-additional-audio-outputs-of-a-multi-out-VST-AU-plug-in)):

- Load a multi-out plug-in into a MIDI track.
- Create an audio track.
- In the upper "Audio From" chooser (Input Type) select the track containing the multi-out plug-in.
- In the lower "Audio From" chooser (Input Channel) select the sub-out of the plug-in.
- Set the audio track's Monitor switch to "In".
- Repeat these steps for any additional output you want to use.

[image]

Let us know if that works.

Comment: Hello Todd and thanks for your efforts. I performed the aforementioned steps and hence that why I was perplexed by the limited number of channels. I have an Ableton 9.7.1 Suite so the number of audio channels shouldn't be a problem. I added a pic to clarify the situation.

Comment: @user3488736 Check your BFD3 output settings. Do you know what the difference is between the s-outputs and the m-outputs?

Comment: s-outputs stands for stereo out while m-outputs stands for mono out. BFD3 output settings should be correct as all m-outputs 1-8 are perfectly routed into Ableton. But I can't select m-outputs 9-16 in Ableton even if they are set within BFD3.